# How to use HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA properly

Tags: php

I'm using `$guui = file_get_contents("php://input");` to receive data from POST method.

But It always returns empty. I have researched and some people said that i must change php.ini and update version.

But where is the php.ini file and how can i do that?

Comment: This makes no sense. `file_get_contents` never returns `null`. At worst, it will return an empty string or `false`. Post the actual code, and maybe a var_dump as well.

Comment: Sorry i have a mistake. Exactly it returns empty string.

Comment: What do you want to reach by that? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_POST` until you really have a good reason not to.

Comment: A good reason would be to process the raw data for XMLRPC requests, for instance.